# Service changes the icon of a menu item

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I had this intent service in my application and I want to change the icon of an item in the menu dynamically  according to the state of the service (started/ finished).
In other words, I want the service to change the icon of the item when it is finished.

This my code for the moment:

*In the activity:

```
.....
public static Menu menu;
......
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

     this.menu = menu;       
     return true;
}
```

*In the service :

```
@Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

  ......              
    MainActivity.menu.getItem(0).setIcon(this.getResources().
     getDrawable(R.drawable.myicon));
 .......
  }
```

This may seem to be a trivial issue, but it does really cause me a headache.
Help please.

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: this code raise an exception

Comment: What exception? Post logs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really a bad idea to have a static reference to the Menu or even MenuItem. I would suggest to use [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html). In this case your code will look like:

**Intent service:**

```
public class IntentService extends android.app.IntentService {

    public static final int CODE_CHANGE_ICON = 122;
    public static final String EXTRA_ICON_ID = "icon_id";

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        final ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(TestActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER);

        if(receiver != null) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(EXTRA_ICON_ID, 20);
            receiver.send(CODE_CHANGE_ICON, args);
        }
    }
}
```

**And the activity:**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER = "receiver";
    private MenuItem mItem;

    private ResultReceiver mResultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()){
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if(resultCode == IntentService.CODE_CHANGE_ICON){
                int drawableId = resultData.getInt(IntentService.EXTRA_ICON_ID);
                if(mItem != null)
                    mItem.setIcon(drawableId);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, IntentService.class);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
        startService(i);
    }
}
```

I know that this solution looks overcomplicated but it's nicer way to perform such operations. Also it's possible to perform such operations by using EventBus.

Answer (score 0):

actually, I found the error: I must execute my code in the UI thread. 
This is my code now:

```
.....
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
......
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
......              
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {

   MainActivity.menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().
   getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_save));

    }
});
.......
}
```